# header file (.text+0x15): undefined reference to

Tags: c, header-files

I write simple header file when I compile I get the error

```
/tmp/ccOH3HcX.o: In function `main':
sample.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `f'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

whatever.h

```
#ifndef WHATEVER_H_INCLUDED
#define WHATEVER_H_INCLUDED
int f(int a);
#endif
```

Example whatever.c

```
#include "whatever.h"

int f(int a) { return a + 1; }
```

sample.c

```
#include "whatever.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("%d\n", f(2)); /* prints 3 */
    return 0;
}
```

To compile it :

```
$ gcc -c whatever.c -o whatever.o
$ gcc -c sample.c -o sample.o
```

Comment: You aren't showing the command line that actually produces the error.  Please update your question with that since that's actually the crux of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the object file whatever.o on the second gcc compilation line.

A simple `gcc whatever.c sample.c -o sample` should do it

Answer (score 2):

The compiler steps you gave only create object files, not an executable. I suppose you did something like

```
gcc sample.c -o sample
```

afterwards and then got the error?

You have to link the object files to get an executable, like so:

```
gcc whatever.o sample.o -o executable_file
```